# Trying to understand the flow of packets going from one VLAN to another

Tags: vlan, subnet

I am trying to understand the flow of the packets from one computer to the other in the same VLAN but on a different subnet [as explained here](http://what-when-how.com/data-communications-and-networking/backbone-network-architectures-data-communications-and-networking-part-2/). And a case shown is:

> Suppose the same sending computer (179.58.10.102) wants to send a
>   message to a computer on a different subnet in the same VLAN (e.g.,
>   179.58.7.30 on the same switch or 179.58.11.20 on switch 3)

The original computer will pack the frame with the destination Ethernet address of its router, and then later it states:

> The router creates a new Ethernet frame and sets the destination
>   Ethernet address to the destination computer

How can the router know the address of the destination computer if initially, the frame was packed with only the router’s address? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ethernet address on the frame is the MAC address of the router (layer 2). The payload of the ethernet frame, like an IP packet (layer 3) still contains the original destination IP address. The router will create a new frame frame with the MAC address of the destination computer containing the original payload.